# ExpressionEngine Expresso Store Price Filter in DropDown Select Menu Dynamically Setting Values Question

Tags: expresso-store

We’re currently working on http://goo.gl/Cxk5Aw and the client would like to add a price min / max filter on the sidebar, but we’re having an issue with keeping the segments of the url clean. I was curious if it was possible to add the min / max into our drop-down menu and have the data stored in segment_3 like we have for the pagination entry display value & sort by?

Current Code:

Drop Down List

```
{exp:dynamo:form return="products/specials" search_id="{segment_3}" id="options_form"}
                                <p>Show <select class="form_option" name="limit">
                                <option value="9" {if limit == 9} selected="selected"{/if}> 9 </option> 
                                <option value="18" {if limit == 18} selected="selected"{/if}> 18 </option> 
                                <option value="27" {if limit == 27} selected="selected"{/if}> 27 </option>
                                </select> 
                                per page</p>
                                <p>Sort by <select class="form_option" name="orderby"> 
                                <option value="title" {if orderby == 'title'} selected="selected"{/if}> Name </option> 
                                <option value="price" {if orderby == 'price'} selected="selected"{/if}> Price </option>
                                </select></p>
{/exp:dynamo:form}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('.form_option').change(function(e){
        console.log('Change');
        $('#options_form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Store Code:

```
{exp:store:search channel="products" limit="9" dynamic="yes" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic_parameters="limit|orderby" search_id="{segment_3}" paginate="both" search:on_sale="yes"}
                    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" form_class="form-horizontal" return="store/shopping-cart"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{exp:dynamo:form return="products/specials/" search_id="{segment_3}" id="options_form"}
                            <p>Show <select class="form_option" name="limit">
                            <option value="9" {if limit == 9} selected="selected"{/if}> 9 </option> 
                            <option value="18" {if limit == 18} selected="selected"{/if}> 18 </option> 
                            <option value="27" {if limit == 27} selected="selected"{/if}> 27 </option>
                            </select> 
                            per page</p>
                            <p>Sort by <select class="form_option" name="orderby"> 
                            <option value="title" {if orderby == 'title'} selected="selected"{/if}> Name </option> 
                            <option value="price" {if orderby == 'price'} selected="selected"{/if}> Price </option>
                            </select> </p>
                            <p>Min: <select class="form_option" name="search:price:min"> 
                            <option value="0" {if search:price:min == '0'} selected="selected"{/if}> 0 </option> 
                            <option value="100" {if search:price:min == '100'} selected="selected"{/if}> 100 </option>
                            <option value="200" {if search:price:min == '200'} selected="selected"{/if}> 200 </option>
                            <option value="300" {if search:price:min == '300'} selected="selected"{/if}> 300 </option>
                            <option value="400" {if search:price:min == '400'} selected="selected"{/if}> 400 </option>
                            <option value="400" {if search:price:min == '500'} selected="selected"{/if}> 500 </option>
                            </select></p>
                            <p>Max: <select class="form_option" name="search:price:max"> 
                            <option value="1000" {if search:price:max == '1000'} selected="selected"{/if}> 1,000 </option> 
                            <option value="500" {if search:price:max == '500'} selected="selected"{/if}> 500 </option>
                            <option value="400" {if search:price:max == '400'} selected="selected"{/if}> 400 </option>
                            <option value="300" {if search:price:max == '300'} selected="selected"{/if}> 300 </option>
                            <option value="200" {if search:price:max == '200'} selected="selected"{/if}> 200 </option>
                            <option value="100" {if search:price:max == '100'} selected="selected"{/if}> 100 </option>
                            </select>
                            </p> 
{/exp:dynamo:form}
```

Product Display Set-Up:

```
{if segment_3 ==''}
                    {exp:store:search channel="products" limit="9" dynamic="yes" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic_parameters="limit|orderby" search_id="{segment_3}" paginate="both" search:on_sale="yes" search:price:min="0" search:price:max="100000"}
                    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" form_class="form-horizontal" return="store/shopping-cart"}
                    {if:else}
                    {exp:store:search channel="products" limit="9" dynamic="yes" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic_parameters="limit|orderby" search_id="{segment_3}" paginate="both" search:on_sale="yes" search:price:min="{segment_3}" search:price:max="{segment_3}"}
                    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" form_class="form-horizontal" return="store/shopping-cart"}
                    {/if}


                        <input type="text" value="1" size="3" name="item_qty" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;">
                        <div class="product">
                            {exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1"}
                            {product_gallery limit="1"}
                            <img src="{image:url:listing}" alt="{title}"  />
                            {/product_gallery}
                            {/exp:channel_images:images}
                            <h3><a href="{path="products/item/"}{categories show_group="1"}/{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"}">{title}</a></h3>
                            <p class="product-description">
                            {exp:trunchtml chars="60" ending="..."}{product_description}{/exp:trunchtml}  
                            </p>
                            <p class="product-price">{if on_sale}{price}{if:else}{regular_price}{/if}</p>
                            <a href="{path="products/item/"}{categories show_group="1"}/{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"}">
                            <div class="glass"></div>
                            </a>

                            <button class="add-to-cart" type="submit" value="Add to Cart"></button>
                            {!--<a href="#"><div class="add-to-cart"></div></a>--}    
                        </div>
                        {/exp:store:product}
                        {/exp:store:search}
```

We set it up use a version of exp:store:search or the other dependent on if segment_3 was empty or not.  This allowed us to store the min / max values in the search_id which also assists in making the url cleaner and helps with the sites category filter (we don't have to account for two additional segments - min / max)